# Rotate properties Mayavi python

Tags: python, mayavi

I am using Mayavi Data Visualizer to plot in python a 3D object using triangular_mesh, I am trying to chage the color of each triangle of the object with this code:

vertices: points of the object, 
faces: faces of the object, 
color: new color of each face of the object.

```
# Create the 3D object
mesh = triangular_mesh(vertices[:, 0], vertices[:, 1], vertices[:, 2],faces)

# Change the color of each face of the object
cell_data = mesh.mlab_source.dataset.cell_data
    cell_data.scalars = color
    cell_data.scalars.name = 'Cell data'
    cell_data.update()
mesh = mlab.pipeline.set_active_attribute(mesh,cell_scalars='Cell data')
mlab.pipeline.surface(mesh)
```

The above code works good, my problem is that I need to actualize the color after taking new data, having active the properties of rotate the object during the process.
Somebody knows how can I do that?

I've tried 
    draw()
but i still can not rotate the object.
I've tried
    show()
And I can rotate the object but I have to close the window to the process continue

Comment: I removed the matplotlib tag because this question does not have to do with matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to parse and I am not sure specifically what operations you are having trouble with, but from what I can tell the major issue is not being able to dynamically update the surface object without calling `mlab.show`.

Try implementing a solution similar to the tutorial [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mlab_interactive_dialog.html#example-mlab-interactive-dialog) which sets up GUI events to adjust the visualization as desired.